# $scope selectively updating on service resolving

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Issue

I have a service that asynchronously fetches data and provides this to a controller. There, it is attached to the `$scope` and used in the view.
What I do not understand is the differences in updating, depending on how this service is used in the controller.

### Example

The service is not providing promises to data, but rather exposing the data itself. I've simulated it below with timeouts:

(edit: I've added initialisation to the `Opt` variable to show that that does not solve the issue.)

```
app.service("Options", ["$q", "$timeout", function ($q, $timeout) {
    var Opt = {
        people:[],
        symbols:[],
        countries:[]
    };

    $timeout(function () {
        Opt.people = [ {frst: "Johnny", last: "Walker"},
                       {frst: "Jack", last: "Daniels"},
                       {frst: "Jim", last: "Bean"} ];
    }, 1000);

    $timeout(function () {
        Opt.symbols = [ {name: "Pi", descr: "circles"},
                        {name: "Phi", descr: "ratios"},
                        {name: "Psi", descr: "waves"},
                        {name: "Chi", descr: "distributions"} ];
    }, 2000);

    $timeout(function () {
        Opt.cities = [ {name: "Amsterdam", country: "Netherlands"},
                       {name: "Cairo", country: "Egypt"},
                       {name: "Santiago", country: "Chile"} ];
    }, 3000);

    /* etc */

    return Opt;
}]);
```

This is then used in the controller like so:

```
app.controller("Ctrller", ["$scope", "Options", "$timeout", function ($scope, Options, $timeout) {
    $scope.options = Options; //updating
    $scope.symbols = $scope.options.symbols; //not updating
    $scope.symbols = Options.symbols; //not updating either

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.symbols = $scope.options.symbols; //updating
    }, 4000);

}]);
```

I've created a live demo in Plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/w5IuJrGNdncIz6tEheUg).

As you can see, the second `select` element in the view (and the 'symbol' property of `$scope`) is updated after 4 instead of 2 seconds. If there were no `$timeout` in the controller, this would not happen at all of course.

Why is this so? Why are the changes not cascaded through?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign `$scope.symbols` to `$scope.options.symbols` or `Options.symbols` before the `symbols` array exists in the object returned by the `Options` service, so it (`$scope.symbols`) is assigned `undefined` rather than a reference to the symbols object.  You can see this by adding a couple console statements before you attempt the assignments.  Since the `symbols` object doesn't yet exist, your `$scope.symbols` variable can't reference it.

This isn't a problem with `people` or `cities` because you're accessing them through the `$scope.options` object which references the `Opt` object returned by the `Options` service.  Since the base reference remains constant, your `ng-repeats` see changes to the `people` and `cities` children objects.

If you really want to assign `Options.symbols` to `$scope.symbols`, you could accomplish it with a watch on `$scope.options.symbols`:

```
$scope.$watch('options.symbols', function(value) {
    $scope.symbols = value;
});
```

**Edit after the example plunker was updated**

The revised plunker still exhibits the same behavior because the initialized `people`, `cities`, and `symbols` are being overwritten in the `$timeout`.  If you want to keep the reference the same you must not use the `=` operator in the `$timeout`.  One option would be to iterate through the returned list and add each item with a push:

```
$timeout(function () {
    results = [ {name: "Pi", descr: "circles"},
                {name: "Phi", descr: "ratios"},
                {name: "Psi", descr: "waves"},
                {name: "Chi", descr: "distributions"} ];
    angular.forEach(results, function(result) {
        Opt.symbols.push(result);
    });
}, 2000);
```

[Here is a revised plunker with my suggested changes.](http://plnkr.co/edit/PbKJaMZvTp6hONJNZsto)

There may be better ways to accomplish this, but the key point is you can not reassign `Opt.symbols` to some other object (even if that other object is also an array).

Another approach would be to change `Opt.symbols` to be an object with an array inside it, your reference `$scope.symbols` points to the object (`Opt.symbols`) and can look at the internal values.

```
Opt = {
    people: [],
    symbols: {},
    cities: []
}

$timeout(function() {
    Opt.symbols.values = [ {name: "Pi", descr: "circles"},
                           {name: "Phi", descr: "ratios"},
                           {name: "Psi", descr: "waves"},
                           {name: "Chi", descr: "distributions"} ]; 
}, 2000);
```

If you went that route, you would need to adjust your ng-options to look like,

```
ng-options="s as s.name for s in symbols.values"
```

[Here is a working plunker of this approach.](http://plnkr.co/edit/r0ay41M6hUe9x51zDmnL)

There are other approaches you could take beyond the two I've given examples for, which makes sense for your project will have to be a decision for you to make.  The key point is that in the `$timeout` you cannot reassign the value of `Opt.symbols` and expect `$scope.symbols` to reference the new value.

Comment: I thought about by reference/by value problem before, and tried initialising `Opt` with its declaration (with `var Opt = {people:[], symbols:[], cities:[]};` in the service) so that a reference to the `Opt.symbols` array could be made instantly -- which could then be updated in the service.         However, that too doesn't work, and I don't know why that is the case.

Of course I could add a watch, but that's 'last resort' in my opinion.

Comment: And, as to why: the reason I want to save reference to `Options.symbols` in a seperate variable is, that it is part of the attributes to a custom directive (called `table`). I'd like to collect all those attributes into a single object to keep better track of them, like so e.g. `$scope.tblAttr = {header: true, colors: ['red', 'orange'], symbols: Options.symbols /*or $scope.options.symbols*/, colCount: 5}`. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @ElRudi I've expanded my answer and have hopefully addressed your questions.  Let me know if it still isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

In index.html you correctly specified the ng-options for 'options.people' and 'options.options' but forgot to do so for 'symbols'

Before:

```
ng-options="s as s.name for s in symbols"
```

After:

```
ng-options="s as s.name for s in options.symbols"
```

Here's the new plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HqPQM5Qqfq7gi9KWQLKJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks , but that was intentional to show the problem :)